# How to disable tabs from the activities?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have 2 activities, 
The first activity consist of two buttons that goes to the second activity.

The second activity consists of 2 tab host.

I want to enable the 2nd tabhost from the button of the first activity. how can i do that, please help me and thank you... ^_^

The First Activity Code:

```
public void OnClickRanoNews(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRanoNews) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RanoNews.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}

public void OnClickRanoNews2(View v)
{
        if(v.getId()== R.id.btnRanoNews2)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RanoNews.class);
            startActivity(i);
            //I want to disable the second tabhost in this button
        }
}
```

The Second Activity Code:

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec
    tabSpec  = tabHost.newTabSpec("rano news");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabRanoNews);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Rano News");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec  = tabHost.newTabSpec("adding form");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabAddingForm);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Adding Form");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i mean i want to disable the 2nd tabhost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void OnClickRanoNews2(View v)
{
        if(v.getId()== R.id.btnRanoNews2)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RanoNews.class); 
            i.putExtra("msg", "0");
            startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

on the second Activity

```
if(getIntent() != null){
      if(getIntent().getStringExtra("msg").equals("0")){
         tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: nope its not working and my first button unfortunately have made the app crash

Comment: guess what, i figure out by myself and combining both of your answers. This is what i do to the code

Answer (score 0):

Just pass additional extra parameter to new activity (in Bundle)

```
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRanoNews2) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RanoNews.class);
        i.putExtra(RanoNews.TABHOST_ENABLED, false /* put your value here */);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

And handle it in new activity as last line of `onCreate()` method

```
    public static final String TABHOST_ENABLED = "tabhost_enabled";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* TabHost initialization */

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            boolean isEnabled = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(TABHOST_ENABLED);
            tabHost.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i was wandering what would be the value that i put?

Comment: @Squall79 If you want to make it enabled - put true, false - otherwise

Comment: You can also check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: I try already, but still the second tabhost is still enabled when i clicked both of the button from the first activity...

Comment: @Squall79 Did you put false as TABHOST_ENABLED ? See edited answer.

Comment: On the first Activity, the TABHOST_ENABLED i put it false, while on the second activity, i put setEnabled to true, but still but buttons can click the second tab host

Comment: @Squall79 you should put value from intent's extra. So if you put false in main Activity, value should be same in second activity

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do to the First Activity Code:

```
public void OnClickRanoNews(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRanoNews)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RanoNews.class);
            i.putExtra("msg","0");
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }
    public void OnClickRanoNews2(View v)
    {
            if(v.getId()== R.id.btnRanoNews2)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RanoNews.class);
                i.putExtra("msg","1");
                startActivity(i);

            }
    }
```

Second Activity Code:

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec
        tabSpec  = tabHost.newTabSpec("rano news");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabRanoNews);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Rano News");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec  = tabHost.newTabSpec("adding form");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabAddingForm);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Adding Form");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        if(getIntent()!=null)
        {
            if(getIntent().getStringExtra("msg").equals("0"))
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(true);

            else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("msg").equals("1"))
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @akhil Batlawala for solving my problem, please do commend if there's something wrong with the answer code above.